# parameters for #pragma clang diagnostic ignored?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, clang, warnings, diagnostics

I've met a warning "Implementing unavailable method" because I've implement the `allocWithZone:` method, which is marked as `OBJC_ARC_UNAVAILABLE`. I want to use

```
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored
```

to ignore it. The question is I cannot find the parameter string responding to "Implementing unavailable method"

Here are what I've looked up in and there is no item about "Implementing unavailable method" or "objc arc unavailable":

- http://fuckingclangwarnings.com/
- https://clangwarnings.com/
- http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#diagnostics_pragmas

Comment: You're going to need to explain what you're trying to accomplish. I can't think of a single reason to override `+allocWithZone:` since memory zones are no longer used in Objective-C.

Comment: @JamesBucanek to do something like [this](https://gist.github.com/macmade/6250215)

Comment: That monstrous macro already had an ARC friendly implementation (which, as you'll notice, does not override `-allocWithZone:`). So the code in question simply should not be compiling with ARC enabled. The preprocessor test I use is `#if __has_feature(objc_arc) && __clang_major__ >= 3`, which has always worked for me. Replace the `#ifdef OBJC_ARC` line with that and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you @JamesBucanek for your reply. That's a work around. But the real question I care about is how to ignore the "Implementing unavailable method" warning. Where can I find all the available parameters for `#pragma clang diagnostic ignored`. Besides, there are versions that overwrite `-allocWithZone` in ARC environment, and it would be called actually. So I still want overwrite it in ARC and I still need to use `#pragma clang diagnostic ignored`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html) Clang 8 documentation

DIAGNOSTIC FLAGS IN CLANG

Here list all the diagnostic flags.